# How to take lookup values from different sheets and show appropriate result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I take the lookup value from different sheets in a workbook and show it corresponding results. Here is the link to a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/475b62f0ujcqdup/sampleTest.xlsx?dl=0)

Basically, the first three sheets contain a table with headers **ID, Name, Basic, DA, HRA, Gross, Incentive** with different values for each row in the column. Now in sheet4 when I put a value for the **ID** column the vlookup should check in which sheet this value is present and according to that it should show its **Gross** column value and so on..

For example if I enter a value of C005 in the ID field in sheet4, the result in the Gross field should be 6420, if I enter a value of A002 in the ID field in sheet4, the result in the Gross field should be 8774 and so on...

I tried to do something like `=IF(LEFT(A2,1)=A,VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet3!$A$1:$G$13,6,0),IF(LEFT(A2,1)=B,VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet2!$A$1:$G$13,6,0)),IF(LEFT(A2,1)=C,VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$13,6,0)))`
but it is showing error and most importantly it is very long and complicated.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check [Function INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). Probably you could use the names of your tables to select first the table where you want to do the search and then VLOOKUP for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula you need

I am using [`INDIRECT`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function) and [`CONCATENATE`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-concatenate-function)

`=VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(A1,1)="A",1,IF(LEFT(A1,1)="B",2,"")), "!$A$1:$H$16")),1,FALSE)`

> Data I have in Sheet1

[image]

> Data I have in Sheet2

[image]

> The magic in Sheet3

[image]

Comment: Have you seen my sample file? How do I apply your formula to that? I'm struggling...BTW I'm using MS Office 2010

Comment: @TamalBanerjee 

`=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(A2,1)="C",1,IF(LEFT(A2,1)="B",2,IF(LEFT(A2,1)="A",3,""))), "!$A$1:$H$16")),6,FALSE)`

This is what you need

Comment: Thanks for that...BTW, what if the values of the columns **ID** are all numbers or any combination of numbers and letters but each one is unique then I cannot use anything like the function `LEFT` as the values are random, how can that be done (if possible at all)?

Comment: Then you will have 3 `IFERROR`s with 3 `VLOOKUP`s inside each of them.... it will not work like this.

Comment: Can `Index` and `Match` be used instead of `vlookup` for that case, will it be easier and shorter?